# How do I find the HTML behind an InfoPath 2010 Form?

Tags: html, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I am learning InfoPath 2010 and have a form that I am creating, but have two issues that I don't know what to do about. In the form I have created there are several columns (repeating tables). I pulled the data in from a database and have already set the conditions for what I want to be returned in the SQL, under the Data tab. So I have the correct data returning, however the issue is that the data is not in a consistent even row across the form (lines on a piece of paper) the lines begin to become offset by the second row and continue to the last. I have tried creating a table to put the data into and was hoping that this issue would go away, but that is not the case. How do I fix this cosmetic issue? OR where do I find the HTML code? When I select "Code Editor" under the Data tab, I am given VB code and there is not much code to work with.

Thank you for your help in advance.

CompGeekess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InfoPath actually creates an XML document, not HTML (if you right-click on a field in your Data Source you'll see a "Copy XPath" option). The best way to control your layout is using a Layout Table (Tools -> Design Tasks -> Layout)

I would recommend avoiding setting pixel values as well, and leaving control heights to "auto" whenever possible. If you're using a layout table and having alignment issues, right click in the table and go to Properties. You'll have Horizontal and Vertical cell alignment options (for the cell contents) in the Table and Cell tabs. You can also select multiple cells (just select the contents of them) and then assign that alignment to all in the same way.

Comment: @Dave- Thank you Dave, I like your answer much better than what I have found on my own.

Answer (score 1):

As I was continuing to find the resolution to my delima, I noticed that when a you have a column selected, Properties and Layout tabs appear at the top. In the Properties tab you can set the width and height of the column using in, and px. I noticed that not all of the columns had the same height in px, so I made each the same height, saved and previewed the form and now the rows are no longer offset. Interesting how something SO simple can make a huge different. The difference was only 2px off.